Emular Android para entrar a una web local
estoy haciiendo una web en ASP.NET y quiero ir viendo como va quedando en la vista desde un dispositivo androd, para eso se me ocurro hacer una aplicacon en xamarin Forms con un explorador integrado simple que abra la web apenas inicie con este codgo:
 <WebView x:Name="MyWebView"
          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
          Source="https://www.google.com" />

El tema es que cambio la pagina de google por mi web local de la compu por algunas de las siguentes pero no entra nada:

https://localhost:44389/
https://localhost:44389/NewUser.aspx
https://PC-Name:44389/NewUser.aspx
https://192.168.1.5:44389/NewUser.aspx

Alguien tiene alguna idea sii es posible hacer lo que estoy ntentando o si o si tengo que conlgarla en la web para poder verla.
Saludos.

Revisa el firewall....me queda la duda de porque no usas simplemente el navegador para testear tu web.?

Primero, la PC y el celular en la misma red y usar la IP de dicha PC, no localhost ni el nombre de la máquina, a menos que haya un DNS que resuelva ese nombre a su IP. Luego ver si el puerto está abierto a conexiones fuera de la PC (cosa que dudo si es una sesión de depuración, pero no he intentado conectarme desde otro equipo así que no estoy seguro). Lo puedes verificar con el comando netstat -a, viendo en qué interfaces está abierto el puerto 44389.  Si solo está abierto en la 127, tocará ver cómo le haces para que lo abra también en la 192. Finalmente, el firewall
